# How to get Twitter tweets done by me with an HTTP Request

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed

Is it possible to simply get the twitter posts done by a particular user into an application with simple http requests without logging in. As xml or json format.

what I want to do is I want to get my twitter feeds as xml or json with a request, is it possible to do that.

Could someone post example http request if its possible to do so.

Thank you and Kind Regards,

[Tharindu Madushanka](http://tharindufit.wordpress.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the user is not protected you can do it with this api call:
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-user_timeline

you will pass an "id" parameter of the user_id or screen name of the public twitter user.

enjoy